# На windows 10 ltsb не работает xamarin

Tags: windows, unity3d, xamarin

После очередной обновы 10-ки начал хапать бсоды из разряда videosheduler internal error и driver power state failure. Помучал диспетчер устройств, попереустанавливал дрова и переустановил окна, история история повторилась, тогда поставил ltsb все работает как часы, но есть проблема не работают пакеты nuget xamarina, точнее они отсутсвуют полностью, но в менеджери nuget пишет что они установлены, ребилдил, ресторил, удалял и качал обратно, ничего не помогает. Так же проблемы с unity, на ltsb не дает пользоваться персональной версией, только платными, ну тут я врод обошел, просто качнул экзешник с левого сайта. ( все установнленные windы были девственными msdnками).

Comment: Может из-за этого? Универсальная платформа Windows (UWP). Для разработки приложений Xamarin.Forms для UWP требуются следующие компоненты:  Windows 10 (рекомендуется Fall Creators Update). В ltsb нет компонентов для магазина, универсальных приложений, edge и т.д

Comment: Как я понял на случай разработки uwp в ltsb есть режим разработчика.